# Set the size of frame

Tags: c#, html, frameset

I supossed to display Pictures Library on web browser.  For that i have two html Frames. one should display the menu, and the second one - the content itself.

Now, because the size of my pics can be large, i need to limit (=MAX size) them to the content frame size.

(The resolution of the screen changes from one PC to another, so i get the WIDTH/HEIGHT information from code behind).

When i tried to make it from the - frame "style" attribute, when page loaded, i got style as empty string:

```
<FRAME src="http://localhost/Display_Media/Default.aspx"  
   style =<%# "width:" + Eval("ScrWidth") + ";" + "height:" + Eval("ScrHeight") + ";" %>  
   name=Content scrolling=yes >
```

Where I wrong? And if someone has idea - maybe Can I do it from code behind ?..

Comment: Frames! Wow I have not seen one of these since about 2005. You do realise this died with the ark (or [netscape navigator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator) as it was called then) and [is now depricated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame)

Comment: Sounds like a nice flexbox would bring you into the present era :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a 'width' and a 'height' attribute instead of writing the 'style' attribute. So like this:

```
<FRAME src="http://localhost/Display_Media/Default.aspx"
width="<%# Eval("ScrWidth"); %>" height="<%# Eval("ScrHeight"); %>"
name=Content scrolling=yes >
```